# How To verify signature in C# without passing a padding algorithm

Tags: c#, cryptography, digital-signature

I receive a digital signature signed with this algorithm `sha256WithRSAEncryption` and I want to verify it against a data the only valid way that. I found this:

```
var x509 = new X509Certificate2(File.ReadAllBytes("cer.cer"));
using (var rsa = x509.GetRSAPublicKey()){              
    Console.WriteLine(rsa.VerifyData(data, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
}
```

But there is no padding used in the signing, so is there is another way to verify the signature without providing a padding?

Comment: There cannot be such thing as "without padding" here. If that name doesn't include padding - it doesn't mean there is none, and as you found out yourself - implied padding in this case is pkcs1.

Comment: `sha256WithRSAEncryption` applies actually RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 Padding, [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/76760), which should correspond to `RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1`. Maybe there is another issue. What's the error message?